# Python sending email with gmail UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii'

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

Im having problems with a function that are suppose to connect to google mail and send an email.

The function looks like this:

```
def emailSend(fileInput):

to = ["blah@blah.com","blah2@blah.com","blah3@blah.com"]
toUpdate = to[emailVem]
gmail_user = "lala@gmail.com"
gmail_pwd = "password"
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
header = 'To:' + toUpdate + '\n' + 'From: ' + gmail_user + '\n' + 'Subject:ERROR \n'
print (header)
msg = header + "\nError, kördes senast: \n\n" + fileInput
smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, toUpdate, msg)
print (msg)
print ('done!')
smtpserver.close()
```

The to[emailVem] is needed since i just want one of the email to be sent. It will get me a number between 0-3. The error i get is this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tim\Documents\ErrorArtPython\Test\errorTimeTest.py", line 56, in <module>
    emailSend(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime("F:\\Export\\art_data.txt")))
  File "C:\Users\Tim\Documents\ErrorArtPython\Test\errorTimeTest.py", line 33, in emailSend
    smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, toUpdate, msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 764, in sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any help i can get is much appreciated!

Comment: You have non ASCII characters in your `msg` string...

Comment: Note the 10th character of "Error, kördes senast"

Comment: Use this `msg = msg.encode('ascii', 'replace')`

Comment: THANK U! God damnit im stupid. Couldn't see it...